# Rearranging a Nested List Based on Index

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Let's say we have a nested list

```
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I would like to create a new nested list where each list is organized based on the index

```
new_list = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

I would like to create a function that converts the `nested_list` into the `new_list`, but it's flexible where it can take in nested lists of different sizes/lengths.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 6, 2, 6], [0, 3, 7, 2, 6, 8, 2], [1, 3, 6, 2, 5]]

max_length = max([len(l) for l in nested_list])

new_list = [[l[i] for l in nested_list if i < len(l)] for i in range(max_length)]

print(new_list)
```

First, we find what is the longest length list we have in our nested list. In this case, it's a length of 7. Then we iterate `i` from 0 to 7 (non-inclusive) and through each individual list and grab the item in index `i` only if the index `i` exists for that list. The code uses [list comprehension](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-comprehension/) to do all this compactly, but if spelled out, it sort of looks like:

```
list_lengths = []

for l in nested_list:
    list_lengths += [len(l)]

max_length = max(list_lengths)

new_list = [[] for i in range(max_length)] # Create max_length empty lists

for i in range(max_length):
    for l in nested_list:
        if i < len(l):
            new_list[i] += [l[i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

From this code you can gain information of which nested list value the value is taken.

**Code:**

```
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 10, 3, 1, 6, 2], [3, 4, 5, 2]]

max_length = max([len(l) for l in nested_list]) #Finding maximum length of nested lists

res=[]
for i in range(max_length):
    tmp=[]     #created a tmp list
    for l in nested_list:
        if i<len(l):
            tmp.append(l[i]) 
        else:
            tmp.append("-")  
    res.append(tmp)    

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 4, 8, 3], [2, 5, 10, 4], [3, 6, 3, 5], ['-', 7, 1, 2], ['-', '-', 6, '-'], ['-', '-', 2, '-']]
```

You can tell in result

```
1st nested list all values are obtained
2nd nested list all values are obtained
3rd nested list all values are obtained
4th nested list 3 values are obtained and you can also say that the values obtained is from 2nd,3rd,4th nested list.
5th nested list 1 value is obtained and it is from 3rd nested list. same as for 6th nested list.
```